# Math.round gives a decimal number in android

Tags: java, android, math

I have this fuction:

```
enemigo.posZ = 5.1529696E8 //This is the value at runtime, it's a float.
double posicionZ = Math.round(enemigo.posZ*100.0f)/100.0f;
```

And this is the output, but why? It should round it to an integer!

```
posicionZ = 2.1474836E7
```

Comment: 2.1474836E7 _is_ an integer. It's the scientific notation of 21474836.

Comment: Note an "E" at the second last place.

Comment: sorry didnt knew it! so it seems to be a bug on the server side

Comment: So if I just want round it to have 3 character how I can do it?

Comment: you can convert like this long posicionZ = ((long)enemigo.posZ);

Comment: Round it after you split it from rest of the digits you dont want.

Comment: Shouldn't `posicionZ` be something that looks more like `enemigo.posZ`?  One is ~24 times as big as the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*An integer with a lot of digits that begins with 21474... should be a clue!*

Java has two versions of [`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)):

```
public static int Math.round(float a)    // float  -> 32-bit int
public static long Math.round(double a)  // double -> 64-bit long
```

Let's look at the code:

```
double posicionZ = Math.round(enemigo.posZ * 100.0f) / 100.0f;
```

Since `enemigo.posZ` is a float, the first version is used. It wants to return `enemigo.posZ * 100.0`, or 51529696000.0, as a 32-bit int, but it can't because it overflows. So it returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, or 2^³¹ - 1 = 2147483647. Then the divison by 100.0f returns 21474836.0, which is 2.1474836E7.

Comment: so to make it work, I need to cast the parameter to long?